# How precision consideration works in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have read this many times in C programming language that by default any floating-point value is of type double not float, So when we write.

**float PI = 3.14;**

then **PI will have a value 3.14-some_small_value**, this is due to **precision consideration**, because **8 bytes** values is now assigned to **4 bytes variable**. Can anyone please explain that how does it happen in terms of memory, or internally how these values are changed.

Comment: If anyone votes down this question then please mention your comments..

Comment: If am not wrong, that conversion is implementation defined.

Comment: You probably want to read [this](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the change you observe does not have much to do with conversion from 8-byte format to 4-byte format. Your `PI` will be different from `3.14` regardless of whether you declare it as `float` or `double`. Value `3.14` is impossible to represent precisely in binary floating-point format. 4, 8 or 1234 bytes is still not enough to build a precise binary representation of `3.14`, since in traditional binary floating-point format this representation is *infinitely long*.

The exact binary representation of `3.14` is

```
11.001000111101011100001010001010001111010... = 11.0(01000111101011100001010001)
```

meaning that the `01000111101011100001010001` part is repeated again and again indefinitely. When you use `float` the whole representation is truncated (or rounded) to the capacity of `float`, while in case of `double` it is truncated to the capacity of `double`. For this reason, any floating-point type will represent `3.14` only approximately. `double` will be more precise than `float`, but still not absolutely accurate.

This rounding is exactly what turns `3.14` into `3.1400001049041748046875` in case of `float` and into `3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446747` in case of `double` (results from GCC compiler). Your compiler might use a different rounding strategy, resulting in slightly different values.

Comment: PI will have a value 3.139998 or something like it, i just want to know that how internally, 3.14 will be changed to 3.139998? :)

Comment: @user2320537: I don't know where you got `3.139998`, but in any case, an implementation can round the value in some implementation-sepcific way. In my experiments with GCC I got the values presented in my answer. Your compiler might round these values differently, so you get a different result.